Allowing an App to be Used from the Lockscreen on iOS
When using the built-in Maps application on iOS, if you lock the device while navigation is active, the navigation screen will still be accessible even while the device is locked. However, this behavior isn't observed with any third-party applications such as Google Maps or Waze.
With my app, after the user begins a task, I need to have a UI that is always visible until the task is over. Is there any method of having a custom UI on the lockscreen similar to Maps, or is that first party privilege?
I went through the background modes and none appear to offer this functionality. As far as I can tell, the only screen that can be created on the lockscreen is using CallKit, which is limited. Even Shortcuts automations cannot create UI on the lockscreen. Lock screen widgets also aren't suitable for my purpose; it needs to be a full-screen UI. Currently, I am using isIdleTimerDisabled, but the user may wish to lock the phone and the UI needs to be immediately visible. Unlocking the phone would be an inconvenience.

I am pretty sure this is a first party privilege.
